# How to type _capitalized_ Czech accented characters with a Czech Programmers' Keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters

Not long ago I started the following thread on how to write Czech with a standard US ASCII
keyboard on Windows 7:

[Writing Czech with US ASCII keyboard on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/653404/how-to-type-czech-characters-on-windows-7-using-cs-language-with-us-internationa)

where I was able to ask the question and obtained some no doubt excellent answers.

However, there is still something that perplexes me. With a Czech Programmers' keyboard,
how do you type a capitalized/uppercase accented character such as "Š" as opposed to "š"?
I am asking because despite the partial solution I suggested I later realized I was not
able to type accented capitalized characters in this way, and, since the external keyboard
I have is a PS/2 keyboard, it is too old and cannot adapt it to a modern USB-only computer
so I cannot tell.

Thanks for letting me know how to type capitalized "Š" with a czech programmer's keyboard.

Regards.

---

Following the answer that KLC could be used to solve the problem, I have posted the
screenshots of MSKLC running displaying the Czech Programmers' Keyboard layout below:

[image: MSKLC Czech Programmer's Keyboard Screenshot 1]
[image: MSKLC Czech Programmer's Keyboard Screenshot 2]
[image: MSKLC Czech Programmer's Keyboard Screenshot 3]
[image: MSKLC Czech Programmer's Keyboard Screenshot 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Czech programmer’s keyboard (as included in Win 7) with [MSKLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/goglobal/bb964665.aspx), I found that it has a diacritic key (a dead key for adding a diacritic mark) for háček (or “caron” as character standards oddly call it). It’s on the row with 1 2 ... 0, two keys to the right of “0”, and it seems to have the engraving “ˇ” in the top right part of the keycap. Unfortunately, this placement means that the key needs to be used together with both AltGr and Shift.

So you would need to press down the Shift key and the AltGr key and press that diacritic key, then type S (or another letter that can take a háček).

Comment: Yes, using MSKLC I can go to File -> Load Existing Keyboard... and select Czech (programmers), and on the keyboard that shows up I can tick the Alt+Ctrl (AltGr) checkbox to reveal the Czech characters with the háček (AKA caron) čarka (AKA acute accent) and kroužek (AKA combining ring above). Ticking the Alt+Ctrl (AltGr) checkbox also reveals that when either of the modifier keys Alt+Ctrl or AltGr is pressed, the US ASCII = key and the US ASCII \ key beocme dead keys, which means that they can be used as follows...

Comment: Simultaneously press and then release AltGr and = and then type one of the keys e, s, c, r, z, y, a, i, e, u, SHIFT e, SHIFT s, SHIFT c, SHIFT r, SHIFT z, SHIFT y, SHIFT a, SHIFT i, SHIFT e, SHIFT u to produce the characters é, ś, ć, ŕ, ź, ý, á, í, é, ú, É, Ś, Ć, Ź, Ý, Á, Í, É, Ú.

Comment: The other key may be useful for loan words form German or other languages, as it does not generate Czech diacritics but can be used to place an umlaut (diaeresis) on top of Czech vowels: simultaneously press and then release AltGr and \ and then type one of the keys e, y, u, i, o, a, SHIFT e, SHIFT y, SHIFT u, SHIFT i, SHIFT o, SHIFT a, to produce ë, ÿ, ü, ï, ö, ä, Ë, Ÿ, Ü, Ï, Ö, Ä, respectively.

Comment: However, this covers some of the letters needed to type Czech with a Czech programmers keyboard... except for one particular letter, which is the capital U with the kroužek (AKA combining ring above) which is not covered by the above key combinations. So that leaves the question, how do you enter a Ů with a Czech programmers keyboard?

Comment: Also, while I was able to type the háček on top of capital S, C, R, Z, these letters actually take a čarka so this doesn't work for these characters either. How do you generate proper capitalized Š, Č, Ř, Ž on a Czech programmers keyboard?

Comment: OK, sorry if I did not notice it so readily. To compose a Ů you must hold down AltGr, Shift, and the ` (backquote) key, then release them, and press SHIFT and U together. This generates Ů.

Comment: And also, to generate the characters Š, Č, Ř, Ž, you first hold down AltGr, Shift, and the = key, release the combination, and then type the desired SHIFT and S, SHIFT and C, SHIFT and R, or SHIFT and Z, to generate the desired characters Ř, Ž, Č, Ž, respectively. Also, I noticed since you are typing SHIFT twice in succession, you do not need to release the SHIFT key to actually produce the combinations.

Comment: This really does complete the entire set of characters needed to type Czech on a Windows 7 computer using a US ASCII keyboard. As an aside, we can also produce the (unneeded) circumflex (press AltGr + SHIFT + \ (backspace character found on the right hand side of the keyboard) and then release and type a vowel) and double acute accent (press AltGr + SHIFT + \ (backspace character found on the left hand side of the keyboard) and then release and type a vowel).

Comment: I've just realized I've missed four letters. To generate these, type AltGr + SHIFT + = and then release and type either of d, t, D, T to get the following: ď, ť, Ď, Ť. Regards.

Comment: I've also just realized that the Czech characters ň, Ň, ó, Ó are also missing from the Czech programmer's keyboard. To enter these use (AltGr + SHIFT + = and n or N) or (AltGr + = + o or O).

Answer (score 0):

To get upper case letter with haček on S.  Š

1. press 'shift' key, hold while you press the key with the plus (+) and the (=) sign on it.  Then release.
2. then depress the shift key and simultaneously the letter you want with the diacritic.  Č Š Ň Ž Ř

For upper case U with diacritic tap the (+ =) button once; then shift & letter U.  Ú.